# How to query and order entities in OData based on a specific rank in a nested JSON data structure?

Tags: odata, azure-cognitive-search

How can I use OData to query entities that are shared with a specific folder and sort them by the rank associated with that folder?

Here is the data structure that I have:

```
[{
    "id": "aaaaa-aaaa-aaa",
    "name": "test",
    "sharedFolders": [
        {
            "id": "xxxxx-xxxx-xxx",
            "rank": 12
        },
        {
            "id": "yyyy-yyy-yyyyy",
            "rank": 32
        }
    ]
},{
    "id": "bbbb-bbbb-bbbbbb",
    "name": "test2",
    "sharedFolders": [
        {
            "id": "xxxxx-xxxx-xxx",
            "rank": 23
        },
        {
            "id": "zzzzz-zzzzz-zzzzz",
            "rank": 65
        }
    ]
}, ...]
```

I would like to query all entities that are shared with the folder with ID "xxxxx-xxxx-xxx" and order them by the corresponding rank (in this case, 12 and 23).

For the folder xxxxx-xxxx-xxx the results should be sorted like that:

```
1. aaaaa-aaaa-aaa
2. bbbb-bbbb-bbbbbb
```

What would be the best way to achieve this using OData?

i tried using following query. But i struggle by only ordering using the specific rank of folder xxxxx-xxxx-xxx

$filter=sharedFolders/any(sf: sf/id eq 'xxxxx-xxxx-xxx')&$expand=sharedFolders&$orderby=sharedFolders/rank